# HTML Dom Parse 5000 + Items

Tags: php, mysql, parsing

Is there anyways to run/write this code below efficiently?

When I run it (Via chrome browser) is always tends to time-out around the 500th item and redirect me back to my homepage.

```
<?php

include_once('config.php');
include_once('simple_html_dom.php');

for($i = 0; $i <= 5000; ++$i){

// Retrieve the DOM from a given URL
$html = file_get_html($url);

// Loop that checks through page contents and retrieves all required
foreach($html->find('div.product-details-contents') as $content) {
$detail['productid'] = $i;
$detail['title'] = $content->find('span.title', 0)->plaintext;
$detail['unit'] = $content->find('span.unit-size', 0)->plaintext;

$sqlstring = implode("','", $detail); 

$sql = "INSERT INTO `cdidlist` (`productid`, `title`, `unit`) VALUES ('$sqlstring')";

if (!mysqli_query($connect, $sql)) {
echo "Error: " . mysqli_error();
}
echo $id . " " . $detail['title'] . " Item Added SUCSESSFULLY! <br>";

    }
}
?>
```

Comment: Why sleep()?  Instead of running 5000 queries in a loop, consider building up a long `VALUES (),(),()` list for multi-insert. You might insert 100 at a time, for example, cutting the number of queries to 50.

Comment: Also, note that even though this isn't a traditional user-input scenario, it is vulnerable to SQL injection! You must escape `$sqlstring`.

Comment: Or use prepared statements.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are opening 5000 webpages and parsing them.  That can't be done that efficiently.  But to keep your script from die'ing, you can use [set_time_limit](http://php.net/manual/en/function.set-time-limit.php)(600) inside of the for loop, making sure that you have an [appropriately high timeout in php.ini](http://www.php.net/manual/en/info.configuration.php#ini.max-execution-time) as well.

**Edit**: you don't own the server.  That means that you are going to have to push it off to the client side.  It would go something like this:

PHP:

```
if(isset($_REQUEST['i'])) {
   $i = (int) $_REQUEST['i']; // sanitize the input
   $error_message = false;
   /*
     load the page, parse the page and input it into the DB.
     If there is an error, save it to $error_message
   */
   if(!$error_message) {
       die(json_encode('ok')); // just die'ing is usually bad, but this is a one-off script
   } else {
       die(json_encode($error_message));
   }
}
```

In your html:

```
<p id="status">Status</p>
<script type="text/javascript" src="//ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">
  $(function () {
     'use strict';
     var get = function (i) {
         if (i > 5000) {
             $('#status).html('complete');
         } else {
            $.get({
                url: window.location.href,
                data: {i: i},
                success: function (data) {
                   if(data === 'ok'){
                      $('#status').html('fetched ' + i);
                      get(i + 1);
                   } else {
                      $('#status').html('error fetching ' + i + ': ' + data);
                   }
                }  
            });
         }
     };
     get(0);
  });
</script>
```

**EDIT 2**: as others have mentioned, this is vulnerable to sql injection.  Please see [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/book.pdo.php) and [PDOStatement](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.pdostatement.php) for prepared statements.

Comment: Hi Matt, how would I go about this if I don't own the server?

Answer (score 2):

For a start, removing `sleep(10);` should save you roughly 50,000 seconds..